# Оптимизация кода С++ / Олимпиадная задача

Tags: c++, оптимизация, производительность, олимпиада

Имеется вот такая задача: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил её так. У нас есть два числа: индекс левой границы и правой. Сначала мы суммируем числа от левой до правой включительно. Если сумма равна заданной, то сдвигаем обе границы. Если получившаяся сумма
меньше заданной, то сдвигаем правую границу. Если же получившаяся сумма больше, то сдвигаем левую границу

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n, k, i, count = 0;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> autos(n);
    for (auto &h: autos) {
        cin >> h;
    }
    int l = 0, r = 0;
    while (r != n) {
        long long sum = 0;
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            sum += autos[i];
        }
        if (sum == k) {
            count++;
            l++;
            r++;
        }
        else if (sum < k) {
            r++;
        }
        else if (sum > k) {
            l++;
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

Но она не проходит последний тест по времени, а именно на 0.081 секунду.
Подскажите, как можно было бы оптимизировать данную задачу.

Comment: При сдвиге границ не суммируйте заново. Сдвинули правую - добавьте одно число, левую - вычтите...

Comment: Можно избавиться от ветвлений... По сути `if (sum < k) { r++; }` эквивалентно например записи `r += sum < k`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При сдвиге границ не суммируйте заново. Сдвинули правую - добавьте одно число, левую - вычтите...

Типа -

```
    else if (sum < k) {
        r++;
    }
```

пишем как

```
    else if (sum < k) {
        r++;
        sum += autos[r];
    }
```

а

```
    else if (sum > k) {
        l++;
    }
```

как

```
    else if (sum > k) {
        sum -= autos[l++];
    }
```

Естественно, цикл суммирования и обнуления `sum` после сдвига границ из кода уберите. Объявление `sum` вынесите за цикл.